# How to represent map with Groovy collectMaps

Tags: groovy

I have a Java code that looks like below code:

```
 for(MyClass myclassObject: input.classes()) {
        if(myclassObject.getName().equals("Tom")) {
            outputMap.put("output", myclassObject.getAge())
        }
    }
```

**How do I efficiently write this with Groovy collectmap?**

I can do
`input.classes().collectEntries["output":it.getAge()]` But how do I include the `if` condition on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `findAll` to keep only items according to condition

and after then apply `collectEntries` to transform items found

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class MyClass{
    int age
    String name
}

def classes = [
    new MyClass(age:11, name:'Tom'),
    new MyClass(age:12, name:'Jerry'),
]

classes.findAll{it.getName()=='Tom'}.collectEntries{ [output:it.getAge()] }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) can take a closure as a parameter. You can apply your logic inside the closure and make sure you return the Map Entry when condition passes and return an empty map when condition fails. Therefore;

```
input.classes().collectEntries { MyClass myClassObject ->
  myClassObject.name == 'Tom' ? ['output': myClassObject.getAge()] : [:]
}
```

However, with your approach there is a caveat. Since you are using the key as `output` and Map does not allow duplicate keys, you will always end up with the last entry in the map. You have to come up with a better plan if that is not your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Since your resulting map is only retaining one value anyway, you can also just do this:

```
input.classes().findResult { it.name == 'Tom' ? [output: it.age] : null }
```

where [findResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#findResult(groovy.lang.Closure)) will return the first item in `classes()` for which the closure:

```
{ it.name == 'Tom' ? [output: it.age] : null }
```

returns a non-null value.

Since you mentioned efficiency in your question: this is more efficient than going through the whole collection using `collectEntries` or `findAll` since `findResult` returns directly on finding the first instance of `it.name == 'Tom'`.

Which way to go really depends on your requirements.